# Collision modifier isn't working with mesh hair

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, hair, collision

I've modeled some hair, converted it into a mesh, modeled the head of this character, and followed a tutorial on how to make my hair animatable and bounce when my character moves. However, whenever she moves, the hair goes right through the body.

I've been trying to figure this out all day, so any help is super appreciated.

link to file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1it-Ps7FwhOhsF1NjE-c6AOiUbOo0dR4L/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial? It also would be helpful to know if the hair has collision detection in the tutorial. I see that you use a Soft Body sim on a Lattice object that deforms the hair mesh. The head has collision enabled. But this will not help you with the collision detection of the hair & head because this only works for the soft body (=lattice object) and the head.